# Platform independent storage of c bitfields

Tags: c, bit-fields

I use C bitfields to store data in memory. For archive usage these data has to be written to a file (and later on be combined with data from another machine). It seems to be a bad idea to save the bitfields directly to the file, since the arrangement of data is implementation specific.

For this reason I wrote some methods to "serialize" these bitfields to save them in a unified format:

```
/* uint16 is a unsigned int with size 16 */

typedef struct {
    uint16 a : 1;
    /* ... just examples ... */
    uint16 z : 13;
} data;

void save_data(FILE* fp, data d) {
    uint16 tmp;
    tmp = d.a;
    fwrite(&tmp,sizeof(uint16),1,fp);
    /* ... */
    tmp = d.z;
    fwrite(&tmp,sizeof(uint16),1,fp);
}
```

While this is perfectly working, it seems not to be well to extend, since adding more members in `data` requires adding the data to the save routine as well.

Is there any trick to automatically convert bitfield data to a unified format *without needing to adapt the routine/macro* when changing the bitfield data?

Comment: _"Is there any trick to automatically convert bitfield data to a unified format without needing to adapt the routine/macro when changing the bitfield data?"_ Unless you're willing to define the bitfield data using macros I have very little hope for you.

Comment: I just can't imagine how to design a macro for this...

Comment: It is not clear why you are singling out bitfields. Everything else about memory layout is just as implementation specific. If you want data portability, you need to have a serialization method for each data item, and you need to change it each time your data item is changed.

Comment: @n.m.: Of course, the question was how to get these serialitation automatically generated (some crazy macros, I thought).

Comment: Do you have other data types besides bitfields? How are you doing it for those data types?

Comment: @n.m.: I use some structs as well, but these can be saved platform independent directly.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not saving your data in a human-readable text format?

Comment: @PP.: I don't know how this is related to my question, but yes: It is *a lot* of data.

Comment: FYI, `sizeof(int)` is also implementation specific. And so is the endianness of the integers. So your solution is not portable.

Comment: @interjay: You are right. In the real code a typedef uint16 is used, that is set architecture-dependent.

Comment: "these can be saved platform independent directly" -- not really. "uint16 is used" -- doesn't buy you much, as endianness and alignment are still very much implementation-specific.

Comment: @n.m.: Okay, i thought the alignment within structs was defined by the standard. Endianness is not, you are right (while this is not a problem in my very special case, since all relevant platforms use the same endianness...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method. I cannot *recommend* it, but it's out there and it *sort of* works, so why not look at it. This incarnation is still platform-dependent but you can easily switch to a platform-independent, possibly human-readable format. Error handling is omitted for brevity.

```
// uglymacro.h
#if defined(DEFINE_STRUCT)

#define BEGINSTRUCT(struct_tag)     typedef struct struct_tag {
#define ENDSTRUCT(struct_typedef)   } struct_typedef;
#define BITFIELD(name,type,bit)     type name : bit;
#define FIELD(name,type)            type name;
#define ARRAYFIELD(name,type,size)  type name[size];

#elif defined(DEFINE_SAVE)

#define BEGINSTRUCT(struct_tag)     void save_##struct_tag(FILE* fp, \
                                                           struct struct_tag* p_a) {
#define ENDSTRUCT(struct_typedef)   }
#define BITFIELD(name,type,bit)     { type tmp; tmp = p_a->name; \
                                      fwrite (&tmp, sizeof(type), 1, fp); }
#define FIELD(name,type)            { fwrite (&p_a->name, sizeof(p_a->name), 1, fp); }
#define ARRAYFIELD(name,type,size)  { fwrite (p_a->name, sizeof(p_a->name[0]), size, fp); }

#elif defined(DEFINE_READ)

#define BEGINSTRUCT(struct_tag)     void read_##struct_tag(FILE* fp, \
                                                           struct struct_tag* p_a) {
#define ENDSTRUCT(struct_typedef)   }
#define BITFIELD(name,type,bit)     { type tmp; fread (&tmp, sizeof(type), 1, fp); \
                                      p_a->name = tmp; }
#define FIELD(name,type)            { fread (&p_a->name, sizeof(p_a->name), 1, fp); }
#define ARRAYFIELD(name,type,size)  { fread (p_a->name, sizeof(p_a->name[0]), size, fp); }

#else
#error "Must define either DEFINE_STRUCT or DEFINE_SAVE or DEFINE_READ"
#endif

#undef DEFINE_STRUCT
#undef DEFINE_READ
#undef DEFINE_WRITE
#undef BEGINSTRUCT
#undef ENDSTRUCT
#undef FIELD
#undef BITFIELD
#undef ARRAYFIELD
```

Your struct definition looks like this:

```
// mystruct_def.h
BEGINSTRUCT(mystruct)
BITFIELD(a,int,1)
FIELD(b,int)
ARRAYFIELD(c,int,10)
ENDSTRUCT(mystruct)
```

You use it like this:

```
// in mystruct.h file
#define DEFINE_STRUCT
#include "uglymacro.h"
#include "mystruct_def.h"

// in mystruct.c file
#include "mystruct.h"
#define DEFINE_READ
#include "mystruct_def.h"
#define DEFINE_WRITE
#include "mystruct_def.h"
```

Frankly, by modern standards this method is ugly. I have used something similar about 20 years ago and it was ugly back then.

Another alternative is using a more humane code-generation facility instead of the C preprocessor.

Comment: You are right, this *is* ugly, but it is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! (The project I'm working on is written in C89 - 20 years of evolution gone past it)

Comment: (I think, something went mixed up in your code, but the idea is clear)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to invest a bit you can use tools like [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/p99__for_8h.html) for "statement unrolling":

```
// in header
#define MY_BITFIELDS a, z
#define WRITE_IT(X) fwrite(&(unsigned){ d.X }, sizeof(unsigned), 1, fp)    
#define WRITE_ALL(...) P99_SEP(WRITE_IT, __VA_ARGS__)


// in your function
WRITE_ALL(MY_BITFIELDS);
```

BTW, never use `int` for bitfields if you can avoid this. The semantic of a set of bits is much better matched by `unsigned`.

With a bit of more macro coding you could even use something like

```
#define MY_BITFIELDS (a, 1), (z, 11)
```

to produce the `struct` declaration *and* the write part.

Comment: I'll have a look on P99. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use a human readable text format?

```
typedef struct {
    int a : 1;
    /* ... just examples ... */
    int z : 13;
} data;

void save_data(FILE* fp, data d) {
    fprintf( fp, "a:%d\n", d.a );
    fprintf( fp, "b:%d\n", d.b );
    ...
    fprintf( fp, "z:%d\n", d.z );
}
```

The advantage of this technique is that somebody using any different language could quickly write a parser to load your data on any machine, any architecture.